Zoho CRM and Zoho Catalyst integration
We're looking into integrating Zoho CRM with Zoho Catalyst and would like to understand the available integration tasks from CRM to Catalyst. Specifically, we're interested in updating data store records in Catalyst whenever module records are created or updated in Zoho CRM. Did someone try this integration?

You can integrate Zoho CRM and Zoho Catalyst in the below two ways:

Create an advancedio function in Catalyst to get the data from the request and insert the same to the Catalyst datastore. You can then invoke the function URL from a CRM function or configure it in outgoing webhooks. The module data will be passed to the function and you can instantly update the data in the datastore by calling the function URL along with the data sent in the request body. You can find the help documentation for creating adnacedio function here.

You can integrate your CRM account under Zoho Event listeners in Catalyst and configure the end module and action to be listened. For eg: You will be able to listen to an event such as Leads updated or created. The event listener will automatically listen to the particular event and pass the data to the event function associated with it. You can then retrieve the CRM data inside the function and perform the datastore insert/update in your event function depending on the action performed in CRM. Also, event listeners is a background running process and you will not get a response to your client since the function will only be invoked by the event listeners. You can find the help documentation for event listeners here.


